# Windows Form Application Radio Button

Tags: c#, radio-button, text-formatting

it is my first time asking here. there is some kind of bug in my program where if i click the rbUnderline the label1 will be underlined but if i click another rb let's say rbBold(obv. the label will become bold) then click the rbUnderline the label wont be underlined again.

here is my code:

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (rbBold.Checked == true)
            {
                label1.Font = new Font(label1.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
            }
            else if (rbItalic.Checked == true)
            {
                label1.Font = new Font(label1.Font, FontStyle.Italic);
            }
            else if (rbUnderline.Checked == true)
            {
                label1.Font = new Font(label1.Font, FontStyle.Underline);
            }





        }
```

Designed.cs Code

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.rbBold = new System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton();
            this.rbItalic = new System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton();
            this.rbUnderline = new System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // label1
            // 
            this.label1.AutoSize = true;
            this.label1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 15.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(58, 65);
            this.label1.Name = "label1";
            this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(158, 25);
            this.label1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.label1.Text = "SAMPLE TEXT";
            // 
            // rbBold
            // 
            this.rbBold.AutoSize = true;
            this.rbBold.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 14.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.rbBold.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(15, 20);
            this.rbBold.Name = "rbBold";
            this.rbBold.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(66, 28);
            this.rbBold.TabIndex = 1;
            this.rbBold.TabStop = true;
            this.rbBold.Text = "Bold";
            this.rbBold.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.rbBold.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.radioButton1_CheckedChanged);
            // 
            // rbItalic
            // 
            this.rbItalic.AutoSize = true;
            this.rbItalic.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 14.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.rbItalic.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(87, 20);
            this.rbItalic.Name = "rbItalic";
            this.rbItalic.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(64, 28);
            this.rbItalic.TabIndex = 2;
            this.rbItalic.TabStop = true;
            this.rbItalic.Text = "Italic";
            this.rbItalic.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // rbUnderline
            // 
            this.rbUnderline.AutoSize = true;
            this.rbUnderline.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 14.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.rbUnderline.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(157, 20);
            this.rbUnderline.Name = "rbUnderline";
            this.rbUnderline.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(110, 28);
            this.rbUnderline.TabIndex = 3;
            this.rbUnderline.TabStop = true;
            this.rbUnderline.Text = "Underline";
            this.rbUnderline.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.rbUnderline.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.radioButton3_CheckedChanged);
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(270, 104);
            this.Controls.Add(this.rbUnderline);
            this.Controls.Add(this.rbItalic);
            this.Controls.Add(this.rbBold);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton rbBold;
        private System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton rbItalic;
        private System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton rbUnderline;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is hard to tell with the posted code. Where did you subscribe the events? Did you try to debug the program to see what is going on?

Comment: Please note that a `CheckedChanged` event gets triggered both on turning the control on __and__ off. Also: Don't you want to allow combinations? The FontStyle can be combined by or'ing them (|) and CheckBoxes would be the controls of choice..

Comment: yes i tried debugging it but i don't know why the label wont be underlined again ( after clicking the rbUnderline twice). 
@TaW yep i know about the | thing. i only need 1 font style per radio button ;)

Comment: Are the radio buttons inside different containers(parent control)? Post some essential code to reproduce the problem, It will be easy for us to help then. Prepare a [sscce](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: man that's all my code :(

Comment: ok, but how is it wired? is this event hooked up with all RBs? Are all RBs in one group? Is there another RB (e.g. 'None')?

Comment: Post designer.cs code also please

Comment: You have bound the checkedchanged of rbUnderline to `radioButton**3**_CheckedChanged` - `this.rbUnderline.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.radioButton3_CheckedChanged);`. What does that do?

Comment: @petelids maybe it's because I accidentally double clicked the radiobutton3 in the design view.

Comment: @jns - wouldn't that cause the issue? If you did that you'd be running an empty event handler for `rbUnderline`. I'm surprised it _ever_ gets underlined...

Comment: @petelids it's okay now man i followed jbriggs solution. thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be a race condition since radioButton1_CheckedChanged will be called twice. That's if all three of your radio buttons are using the same event handler for the CheckChanged event. The event handler will be called once for the button that was clicked and once for the button that gets unchecked.

Try using 3 seperate if statements instead:

```
if (rbBold.Checked == true)
{
    label1.Font = new Font(label1.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
}
if (rbItalic.Checked == true)
{
    label1.Font = new Font(label1.Font, FontStyle.Italic);
}
if (rbUnderline.Checked == true)
{
    label1.Font = new Font(label1.Font, FontStyle.Underline);
}
```

Edit: In response to your update you'll also need to change the following :

```
this.rbUnderline.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.radioButton3_CheckedChanged);
```

to :

```
this.rbUnderline.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.radioButton1_CheckedChanged);
```

Comment: man that worked! thank you so much. I'm new to windows form application and c#. I'm studying only in the internet. Thanks for everyone who helped!

Comment: You should also add the same thing for rbItalic

Comment: If that doesn't work then add a check to make sure the checked option is also the sender.  if (rbBold.Checked == true && sender == rbBold)

Answer (score 0):

You should group radio buttons together, put them in a container like panel or group box, and your problem should be gone.